# Sorting the response from the Foursquare Places API re:two word name?

Tags: api, foursquare

We are trying to query the Foursquare api to query for a two word name:

Cava Grill in Gaithersburg, MD

We are trying this via:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=checkin&query=cava%20grill&near=gaithersburg,%20md&limit=1&oauth_token=SEB14NBLGO4HMFTOXQX0JZTSVGM41ENNKE0X1RXHCI5XP3P5&v=20150420

(don't worry ... this is the public API key from the FS page)

Two odd behaviors:

1. Even though we are explicitly searching for the Cava Grill in Gaithersburg, MD ... the Bethesda, MD one comes up first in the results (odd, why??)
2. Chipotle Mexican Grill shows up in this result set ... we suppose because of the word "Grill"

So ...

a.  anyone know why the Bethesda one would show up higher in the result set? (Should we just narrow the radius tighter?)

b.  anyone know if we can look for the "entire query" vs. each word in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are queried and sorted differently based on your intent.  If you're looking for a specific venue, I suggest changing your intent from checkin to match.  Browse may also be a good choice depending on future search params

Here's the nutshell on the intents:

intent=checkin returns a list of venues where the user is most likely is located

intent=browse returns a list of most relevant venues for a requested region, not biased by distance from a central point.

intent=match returns a single result that, with high confidence, is the corresponding foursquare venue for the query-based request

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  I tried different intents actually.  

match - actually returned a blank result for venues ... only with the city lat/long returned

I wish I could supress "chipotle grill" just because my search term has "grill" in it